# picture element support Chrome on iOS

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome

Checked caniuse.com but I couldn't find anything regarding support for picture element in Chrome on iOS. What's the current support status and where can I find some more info?

http://caniuse.com/#search=picture

Answer (score 0):

Chrome on iOS uses WkWebView which is WebKit. From your link it looks like Safari iOS supports it so Chrome on iOS should too.